# Compton Scattering Assumption: $p^2=m^2$ for electron and $k^2=0$ for photon?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, scattering

In section 5.5 of Peskin, the book assumes that $p^2=m^2$ for electron and $k^2=0$ for photon. Why can we assume this?

Answer (score 2):

It's because $p^2$ in this context is really $p_{\mu}p^{\mu}$, and $p_{\mu}p^{\mu} = (p^{0})^2 - \vec{p}^2.$ We know that $E^2 = \vec{p}^2 + m^2$ and $p^0 = E$, so $p^2 = p_{\mu}p^{\mu} = m^2$

For a photon, the same reasoning shows the $k^2 = m_{photon}^2$, but the photon has no mass so $k^2 = k_{\mu}k^{\mu} = 0.$ It's equivalent to say $(k^0)^2 = \vec{k}^2$